# R fontawesome & ggplot - icons not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-awesome

I paste my code below. I am looking to produce a piechart using ggplot with the legend containing icons for mobile, tablet and desktop using fontawesome. However, despite the pie chart being plotted, I don't seem to get these icons appearing. I find this odd, as if I for example exchange the desktop icon for a TV icon, it works, as do many other icons. I was wondering whether there is something I'm mising?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(emojifont)
library(scales)
library(fontawesome)


load.emojifont("OpenSansEmoji.ttf")
load.fontawesome()


device<-data.frame(`Device`=c("Desktop","Mobile", "Tablet"),
`Proportion`=c(45.7,50,4.3),symbols=c("\UF390","\UE527","\UF3FC"))



# Color palette
pal <- scales::hue_pal()(3)
names(pal) <- c("Desktop", "Mobile", "Tablet")
# Symbol palette
symbols <- c("\UF390", "\UE527","\UF3FC")
names(symbols) <- c("Desktop", "Mobile", "Tablet")

draw_key_symbol <- function(data, params, size) {
data$label <- symbols[names(match.arg(data$fill, pal))]

grid::textGrob(data$label, 0.33,0.33,0.33,
gp = grid::gpar(col = data$fill, 
fontfamily = "fontawesome-webfont", 
fontsize = 3.88 * .pt))
}

ggplot(device, aes(x = "", Proportion, fill = Device)) +
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", key_glyph = "symbol") +
scale_fill_manual(values = pal) +
coord_polar("y") +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
axis.ticks = element_blank(),
panel.grid  = element_blank())+
geom_text(aes(label = paste0(
Proportion,"%"
)),
position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: What OS are you using? What graphics device are you plotting to? Are you using the RStudio plot viewer or the RGUI graphics device? Or are you trying to save to a PDF/PNG?

Comment: WIndows 8. I have tried it both in Rstudio plot viewer, and also in Rmarkdown. Idea is that these pie charts will be in a HTML document